# What do the two armor ratings for Kevlar mean?

Tags: savage-worlds, equipment

I'm making a Savage Worlds campaign in the Shadowrun universe. As such, most players want Kevlar vests as armor, but the armor rating is listed as "+2/+4" and I have no idea what that means. Which do I add to the armor rating?

Answer (score 14):

See the description of Kevlar, a couple pages before the table. The +2 is against most attacks, while the +4 is against only bullets. (Note also that Kevlar negates up to 4 AP on bullets as well, so it's even better against them than just the +4 would indicate.)

Answer (score -3):

With ceramic inserts the damage rating goes to +4/+8. If you want to make a player's life difficult,  you could take away the ceramic benefit after a few hits as the plates can shatter when struck by bullets.